# How to to keep non-serializable objects during ASP.Net web service reinstall?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, installation, upgrade

I have an IIS with ASP.Net web service running, I need to upgrade it from time to time.

There is a collection of non-serializable objects and I would like to keep it alive during reinstall.

I can't put it into database.

Should I use some aside process or service to keep them till new instance of web service will be installed?

Should I separate all functionality into libraries to upgrade and keep data in global.asax?

Or maybe there is a better way to handle this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say if you have processes that need to live outside of the life-cycle of the web service you should keep them in a process where you can control the process life cycle.  I would recommend a windows service where you can control when the service comes and goes.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be logical!